# Как заставить обьект мигать в цикле?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Есть наброски кода небольшие , принцип действия такой , svg-шное изображение должно было с помощью скрипта (БЕЗ CSS , JQUERY)мигать с частотой (3 сек) в цикле ,без нажатия на button . Как такое можно реализовать ?

**ЧАСТЬ JS**

```
    var blink = 1;

function bl() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var element = document.getElementsByClassName('st_OF6');

        if (blink == 1) {
            element.setAttribute("fill", "#18ff44");
            blink++;
        } else {
            element.setAttribute("fill", "#676767");
            blink = 1;
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(bl);
    }, 1000 / fps);
}
bl();
```

**стили самого обьекта ,класс (st_OF6)**

```
.st_OF6{fill:#008837;stroke:#1A1A1A;stroke-width:5;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Первое*: Зачем используете `requestAnimationFrame` в `setTimeout`? Он отложит вызов, не более, да и `delay` будет в "один кадр". `fps` у вас не определена, кстати.

*Второе*:  `getElementsByClassName` вернет коллекцию элементов, что понятно из названия. Поэтому либо обратитесь по индексу

```
 var element = document.getElementsByClassName('st_OF6')[0];
```

Либо ищите через `id`, тогда его нужно будет к элементу добавить

```js
// контролируем fps
const fps = 10;
let lastFrameTime = performance.now();

let blinkStatus = true;
// для оптимизации лучше сразу получить элемент
const element = document.getElementsByClassName('st_OF6')[0];

function blinkElement(time) {
    requestAnimationFrame(blinkElement);
    const now = performance.now();
    // если с последнего фрейма прошло меньше времени чем нужно,
    // то ничего не делаем
    if((now - lastFrameTime) < (1000 / fps)) return;

    element.setAttribute("fill", blinkStatus ? "#18ff44" : "#676767");
    blinkStatus = !blinkStatus;
    lastFrameTime = now;
}

blinkElement();
```

```css
.st_OF6 {
  stroke:#1A1A1A;
  stroke-width:5;
  stroke-linecap:round;
  stroke-linejoin:round;
  stroke-miterlimit:10;
}
```

```html
<svg height="200" version="1.1" width="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" class='st_OF6'>
  </circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: fps  глобальную переменную не скопировало,только сейчас заметил...

Comment: А где же Вы здесь частоту мерцания  задаете ? И я думал чтоб оно по принципу условия работало IF,ELSE .

Comment: @Karter вместо условия тернарный оператор `?`

Comment: Да . Просто я пробовал уже похожее но забыл как строится . Типа есть глобальная переменная которая ровна 1 , если обьект равен этой переменной тогда он будет например зеленый , если нет то тогда мигает красным. Что-то вроде такого .

Comment: @Karter тернарный оператор делает тоже самое, только чуть короче) Добавил управление `fps`

Comment: Да , это оно самое) спасибо огромное

Comment: @Karter нажмите галочку на моем или другом ответе, который вам подошел

Comment: А в IE11 будет оно работать или нет ?

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` поддерживается с 10 версии IE https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame

Comment: странно, пишет что setAttribute не поддерживает ...бред какой-то (

Comment: есть возможность зайти через Team Viever ?

Answer (score 2):

```js
var circle = document.querySelector('circle'),
    flag = true;
function toggleCircle(){
  if(flag){
    circle.style.fill='red';
  }else{
    circle.style.fill='';
  }
  flag = !flag;
}
setInterval(toggleCircle,3000);
```

```html
<svg width="60px" height="60px">
  <circle cx="30" cy="30" r="30" fill="green" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Здесь по моему он просто исчезает ,а не меняет цвет ...

Comment: @Karter , согласен. Невнимательно прочёл вопрос.

Comment: Здесь реально вставить условия как у меня по принципу IF , ELSE?

Comment: Это вместо flag ? circle.style.fill='red' : circle.style.fill='';
  flag = !flag; вписать ?

Comment: Переписал с тернарного оператора на `if-else`

Comment: Суппер , все работает как надо )спасибо тебе огромное )